# Postgresql subquery wheere in statement with string text

Tags: php, string, postgresql, where-clause

my subquery is doesn't make positive effect. Please help. The column elements is string, seperated by comma;

```
select  id, title, elements, (
    select string_agg(distinct street, ',') 
    from locations 
    where elementnames in (replace(quote_nullable(elements),',',''','''))
) as buildings
from events ;


    id     | title |      elements       | buildings
-----------+-------+---------------------+----------
 124003    | alpha | NYCID005            |
 000111    | beta  | NYCID222            | 
 200123    | gamma | NYCID201,NYCID193   | 
 102036    | sigma | NYCID202,NYCID191   | 
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Do ***not*** store comma separated values in a single column. Your problem is a direct result of that bad design

Comment: I can change the schema, please give me an example how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a some solution.

```
    select id,title,elements,
    (select string_agg(distinct street, ',') from locations
    where (string_to_array(elementnames,',') <@ (string_to_array(elements,',')))) as buildings
from events;

    id     | title |      elements       |           buildings       |
-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------+
124003 | alpha      | NYCID005           | Ford,Harrison             |
000111 | beta       | NYCID222           | Stallone,Malkovitch       |
200124 | gamma      | NYCID201,NYCID193  | Gates Street,Ostin        |
```